# How to find subnet mask (errors) in android

Tags: java, android, ip, mask, subnet

Using the below code, which is to find my subnet mask:

```
String subnetMask="/"+networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0).getNetworkPrefixLength();
```

Where my IP address (as obtained from other sources) is 192.168.0.130

But the code above finds the subnet mask to be 255.255.255.255, but I expect it to be 255.255.255.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is networkInterface?

Answer (score 0):

I am not that into java, but `255.255.255.255` is by no means a bad subnet mask; it is quite possible that you are using an interface that binds to a single host subnet, which I believe is the norm when you have dial ups and ADSL.

Find out what that interface really is and how it is setup. That might give you some clues ( assuming that the code is right ).

Comment: i think it isn't, because when i'm testing my app on two different devices (samsung galaxy s3 mini and acer liquid), acer gives me right subnet mask, and samsung the wrong one